# Meaning of colon(:) inside @Path annotation

Tags: java, rest

I am new to `Restful` services. I was going through a code and found this line

```
@GET

@Path("{image:image/.*}")
```

Can someone please explain the meaning and use of the above syntax?

Comment: its just part of regex used...

Comment: @JunedAhsan It is not, at least not the `image:` prefix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Path` notation supports normal strings to match the path or a regex to  match a pattern. In your case

```
@Path("{image:image/.*}")
```

seems to be just matching a pattern of

> Path param {image} with any pattern like image/.*, which basically translates to image/anything , anything here does not refer to the word 'anything' but its literal meaning i.e. any valid text.

**Correction:**
Refer to @Sotirios Delimanolis answer for complete details. Thanks mate for correction input.

Answer (score 4):

The notation is known as URI path templates and described in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/ginpw/).

You define a new template variable by declaring it within brackets `{}`. The JX-RS environment will bind the corresponding path segment from the requested URI to a declared `@PathParam` handler method parameter.

From the documentation

> URI path templates are URIs with variables embedded within the URI
>   syntax. These variables are substituted at runtime in order for a
>   resource to respond to a request based on the substituted URI.
>   **Variables are denoted by braces (`{` and `}`)**. For example, look at the
>   following `@Path` annotation:
>
> ```
> @Path("/users/{username}")
> ```
>
> In this kind of example, a user is prompted to type his or her name,
>   and then a JAX-RS web service configured to respond to requests to
>   this URI path template responds. For example, if the user types the
>   user name “Galileo,” the web service responds to the following URL:
>
> ```
> http://example.com/users/Galileo
> ```
>
> **To obtain the value of the user name, the `@PathParam` annotation may be
>   used on the method parameter of a request method**, as shown in the
>   following code example:
>
> ```
> @Path("/users/{username}")
> public class UserResource {
>
>     @GET
>     @Produces("text/xml")
>     public String getUser(@PathParam("username") String userName) {
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```

The documentation then goes on to specify the syntax for the notation

> **By default, the URI variable must match the regular expression
>   "[^/]+?"**. **This variable may be customized by specifying a different
>   regular expression after the variable name**. For example, if a user
>   name must consist only of lowercase and uppercase alphanumeric
>   characters, override the default regular expression in the variable
>   definition:
>
> ```
> @Path("users/{username: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]}")
> ```
>
> In this example the username variable will match only user names that
>   begin with one uppercase or lowercase letter and zero or more
>   alphanumeric characters and the underscore character. If a user name
>   does not match that template, a 404 (Not Found) response will be sent
>   to the client.

So your example

```
@Path("{image:image/.*}")
```

defines a URI template variable named `image` that contains a segment matching the regex

```
image/.*
```

The JAX-RS environment will therefore use your annotated method for requests to URIs matching

```
http://somehost.com/context-path/image/[anything]
```

Presumably, your method would have a parameter

```
@Path("{image:image/.*}")
public Response handle(@PathParam("image") String path) { /* handling */ }
```

and `path` would have a value of `"image/[anything]"`.