# Insert v1 into @Path annotation (java 1.6)

Tags: java, annotations

Our current path annotation omitted the 'v1' and we'd like to insert it.  Since we cannot have more than one Path annotation, is there a way to add the v1 using a regular expression?  I have seen this used for parameters, but not for constants in the endpoint.

So if my path annotation currently looks like this:

```
@Path("/rest/noun")
```

Can it be replaced with something like this?

```
@Path("/rest/noun|/rest/v1/noun")
```

Since some users are using the original path of /rest/noun, I want to offer the corrected one and the old one, not to break their current functionality.  I want to offer both of these:

```
/rest/noun
/rest/v1/noun
```

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34339420/2055998) helps.

Comment: you want to use two path for one controller? i didn't understant | in /rest/noun|/rest/v1/noun

Comment: @PM the v1 is not a path parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want more than one path for same code of execution, you can create wrapper function calling the current function internally like below:

```
@Path("/rest/noun")
void currentfunction(){
//all functionality code here
}

@Path("/rest/v1/noun")
void newfunction(){
currentfunction();
}
```

Or you can also use:

```
@Path("/rest/{parameter: v1\\/noun|noun}")
void currentfunction(){
    //all functionality code here
    }
```